# ionic 2 with woocommerce wordpress the Products do not appear

Tags: wordpress, ionic2, woocommerce-rest-api

want to make a mobile application using ionic and WordPress. I added the WooCommerce plugin to WordPress and I connected the ionic with it using the API from WordPress. When I tried to retrieve the products, it was failed to view them!! My code in home.ts, home.html and the JSON response are shown in the screen shots. Please help me if you can, any suggestion to solve the problem.

[image: one]
[image: two]
[image: three]

Comment: home and home.ts are not visible. Please post your code through the editor.

Comment: Look at what you printed out `data.body`. This is the array of products. So why then are you trying to get a `products` property from it?

Comment: OK, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

the products do not appear because they are being received from the server, but not shown in the HTML.

You need to render the products on the HTML template with an ngFor.

In your home.html, try adding this:

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of products">
      {{ product.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Then you should see the products in your Home.
See this for more Info:
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngfor/

`

Comment: Look at this part of my home.html , I showed the products inside a slider : `<ion-slides>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let product of products | async">
        <ion-card no-padding>
          <img ng-src="product.featured_src" /> 
          <h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
          <p>{{ product.short_description }}</p>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>`